# Will Windows become corrupted if Ubuntu is dual installed on it

Tags: installation, partitioning

I want to install Ubuntu as a dual partition on top of my Windows 7 Home Basic. I am planning to empty my D Drive (80 GB), and use that space to install the Ubuntu.

However, I have heard some guys saying that if Ubuntu is installed on top of Windows, the latter becomes corrupted. Is it true?

And secondly, after installing successfully (if possible), if I uninstall Ubuntu, will Windows reclaim all the occupied space in the D drive normally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Installing Ubuntu on top of Windows does not corrupt Windows; but yes as Ubuntu uses different file system (ext3 or ext4), this 80 GB partition will not be accessible from Windows.

Later when formatting (if done), change the file system to one recognized by Windows (NTFS or FAT) and free space will be available for Windows.

Comment: At the time of booting, will the laptop give me options as to which OS to load?

Comment: Yes , The problem comes when you install windows over ubuntu(linux in general) then the option for ubuntu does not come as windows don't recognize it. But installing Ubuntu over windows will show you all OS option available.

Comment: Thanks. can you point me to any article which describes in detail how to install Ubuntu on top of Windows 7 in a partition from a CD?

Comment: [link 1: http://opensource-sidh.blogspot.in/2012/04/ubuntu-1204-installationdual-boot-with.html](http://opensource-sidh.blogspot.in/2012/04/ubuntu-1204-installationdual-boot-with.html)
[link 2: http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2011/05/22/how-to-dual-boot-windows-7-and-ubuntu-11-04/](http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2011/05/22/how-to-dual-boot-windows-7-and-ubuntu-11-04/)

Comment: In the first article, they give a link to download the requisite iso image. I have done that. Now do I just copy that iso image into a DVD and try to instal Ubuntu with that?

Comment: Yes or you can make bootable pendrive.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, installing Ubuntu alongisde Windows does not cause any corruption in Windows. Once Ubuntu has it's own space, you will find that it just coexists peacefully.

Secondly, Windows (or Ubuntu for that matter) will not automatically reclaim freed space. Furthermore, you cannot "uninstall" Ubuntu, but rather only format the drive. However, Windows will tell you that there is free space available if you reformat the drive Ubuntu was installed on.

Comment: Yeah yeah, that's what I meant. So if I reformat the drive, will it show all the 80 GB to be available?

Comment: @Cupidvogel: yes.